# Trying to build an interface

Tags: xml

I tried building an interface and it keeps telling me instead of running on the emulator that:

"Integer types not allowed (at width with value '320')

I don't really know why. Is there a value range? If there is, what is it?

2.

My processor speed is 2.0 GHz and as such I cannot run the emulator that came with the Android Studio 1.5 I am currently using. I currently make use of my Techno Y3 in place of the emulator, the OS being 4.2.2 kitkat. The thing is, after running the code on the phone, it doesn't display. Is there a way to go around this please?

Comment: Please paste relevant code examples.

Comment: Well you've certainly provided enough detail.  I forgot, what emulator are you talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most likely need to specify a unit after your integer value, e.g. `'320px'`.

Comment: Thank you so much... It helped.